# IntelliJ/AndroidStudio requiring device/VM for unit tests

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, junit

I started a new project in IntelliJ and out of the box it doesn't quite work. Currently the problem is that when I try to run a unit test it prompts me to pick a device/VM for the code to run on. Except that these are jUnit classes and shouldn't need a device. It really doesn't need anything:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? The project can be viewed [here](https://github.com/tenmilez/InventoryManager%20here), but it's pretty much a stock project.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not provide execution environment of its own, even for unit tests. AS distinguishes between instrumented tests that need Android runtime environment, either device or emulator, and unit tests that can be run on the host computer in Java virtual machine (JVM). But even for the latter you must setup the environment.

See more at https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html